# How to load a Catalog Price Rule by name?

Tags: model, catalog-price-rules

I currently load it by ID, like so:

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can load every (non-EAV!) entity just by adding a second argument to load:

```
$entity->load($value, $column);
```

The problem is, if the column is not unique you get one of the matching entities back, and you don't know which.

For your case this should be:

```
$catalogrule->load('10% to all items', 'name');
```

Comment: Hi I put this code ($catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load('20 OFF PROMO','name')) getting rule but its not working in magento 1.9

Comment: Make sure the name matches exactly. Maybe you have two rules with the same name?

Comment: How to load catalog rule by name in magento 2?

Comment: Hi @JenithSamuel, check if instead of the module 'catalogrule/rule' you have to use 'salesrule/rule' (not a catalog price rule but a cart price rule).